# Knapsack branch and bound: forward filter

Tags: python, optimization, algorithm, recursion

I've coded branch and bound to solve the knapsack problem, and use a **greedy linear relaxation** to find an upper bound on a node I'm currently exploring. What I mean by this is that I first sort the items by their respective *value density* (computed `value/weight`, for each item) and then fill the bag according to a greedy algorithm, using a fraction of the last item that would put us over the bag's capacity. This solution is unattainable (we can't take half an item) but provides an upper bound on the maximum value we *can* attain from considering an item `j`:

```
def _linear_relaxation(self, j, cp, cw):
    # we consider how well we can do to increase our current profit (cp) 
    # by looking at items beyond the item that we either just took or left behind 

    weight = cw
    value  = cp

    for (v, w), index in self.ordered:
        if index > j:

            if w + weight <= self.capacity:
                value  += v
                weight += w
            else:
                return value + (v * (self.capacity - w)/float(w))

    return value
```

My code works great to solve small problems using this relaxation, but starts slowing down when the problem size increases. One optimization (or **reduction on a node's upper bound**) is to avoid taking items of [high value density](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~jopsi/dinf504/chap13.shtml) whose weight exceeds the leftover weight we're trying to fill.

Think about it this way: our greedy linear relaxation bound takes items in decreasing order according to their density, `value/weight`. If the `residual` or remaining weight in the bag is less than the item we're considering adding to the bound, it is much better to take items further down our density list. Consider, for example, `residual = 1`, `weight = 2`. Wouldn't it be great if we found a small `value`, so that we could add to our estimate `value/2`, rather than `2 * value`? We'd get a much better estimate on the least upper bound than if we considered the last item with the greatest density, with no regard as to its relative effect on our upper bound.

With this in mind, a better bound can be found as follows:

```
def _linear_relaxation(self, j, cp, cw):

    weight = cw
    value  = cp

    for (v, w), index in self.ordered:

        if index > j:

            if w + weight <= self.capacity:
                value  += v
                weight += w

            else:
                if w > self.capacity - (w + weight):
                    continue

                return value + (v * (self.capacity - w)/float(w))

    return value
```

This bound is great for a list of no more than 1000 items (around 11 seconds compared to no solution) but fails on a problem with 10,000 items. My question, how can we we do better? Can the bound be improved on? Or can we more smartly consider what nodes are worth adding, based on the best solution discovered so far.

My question/goal of the review:

To provide some context, the code I've written is included below. Please let me know if you have improvements on its structure (for example, is it better practice to make `TreeNode` a truly recursive object and give it `left` and `right` attributes? Do we gain anything by doing this?). What I'm really looking for, though, is how we can improve the current **depth first search** implementation (please don't provide a solution that uses a heap, for example, unless you can demonstrate it is an all around better algorithm than what I've written). If you'd like to provide code, that would be great, but I'm really just looking for some ideas on how my current code might be optimized. I'm kind of new to optimization and don't really know where to look for improvements or really how to think about the problem as might a person with a speciality in optimization.

While searching, if we include an item, do we need to recalculate the bound on this node (or would it just be the value of its parent--this solution is still attainable)?

One optimization I should make: put the right node on after putting on the left node. The order in which we consider expanding a path matters, here!

```
class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self, level, V, W, taken):

        self.level = level
        self.V = V
        self.W = W
        self.taken = taken

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.level, self.V, self.W, self.taken))


class KP:

    def __init__(self, cap, values, weights):

        self.capacity = cap
        self.values   = values
        self.weights  = weights

        # sort the items according to their value per weight 
        self.ordered = sorted([((v, w), i) for i, (v, w) in enumerate(zip(self.values, self.weights))],
                          key = lambda tup: float(tup[0][0])/tup[0][1], reverse = True)

    # our best initial solution will be the greedy solution 
    def _greedy_solution(self):

        weight = 0
        value  = 0
        taken  = []

        for (v, w), index in self.ordered:

            if w + weight <= self.capacity:   # take items of highest value per unit weight, while we still can
                value  += v
                weight += w
                taken.append(index)

            else:
                return TreeNode(index, value, weight, taken)

        return TreeNode(index, value, weight, taken)


    def solve(self):

        best = self._greedy_solution()
        root = TreeNode(0, 0, 0, [])

        stack = [root]

        while len(stack) > 0:

            current = stack.pop()    
            index   = current.level

            if current.V >= best.V:         # consider whether we can immediately improve our best
                best = current

            if index < len(self.values):    # there are items left to consider


                # we have two branches to consider: if we have room, we take the item
                # if we don't have room, we continue our solution to the next iteration 
                # where we consider the next item

                if current.W + self.weights[index] <= self.capacity:
                    taken = list(current.taken)     # update path of items taken
                    taken.append(index)
                                                    # create the right node
                    right = TreeNode( index + 1, current.V + self.values[index],
                                  current.W + self.weights[index], taken )

                    if right.V > best.V:            # update our best, if possible 
                        best = right

                    bound = self._linear_relaxation(index, right.V, right.W)

                                                    # only continue exploring if 
                                                    # we're guaranteed something better
                    if bound >= best.V:
                        stack.append(right)

                                                    # create the left node, continue
                                                    # solution of the parent, without             
                                                    # taking the item 

                left  = TreeNode( index + 1, current.V, current.W, list(current.taken) )
                bound = self._linear_relaxation(index, left.V, left.W)

                                                    # only continue exploring if 
                                                    # we're guaranteed something better
                if bound >= best.V:                 
                    stack.append(left)


        return best
```

Comment: Isn't `solve` supposed use the sorted list of items?

Comment: @JanneKarila It does. Look at how it the solution using `_linear_relaxation`.

Comment: Yes, but it creates the next node at `index+1` where `index` refers to the unsorted list.

Comment: @JanneKarila I see what you're saying. That's a good point. Thank you.

Comment: @JanneKarila If I'm correct, I should create `right` as follows (and apply similar changes elsewhere):

`right = TreeNode( index + 1, current.V + self.ordered[index][0][0], current.W + self.ordered[index][0][1], taken )`

Comment: Yes, and remember to change `_linear_relaxation` to use right index. Also, I suppose the optimization you added to `_linear_relaxation` becomes redundant then.

Comment: As you state that you want to use depth first search, would this approach be of any interest? [Iterative Deepening Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). If it applies, you can use your existing depth first search program so it might not require much additional code...

Comment: This is going to sound dense, because it dense, but how to you input your data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Your first upper bound is buggy

```
return value + (v * (self.capacity - w)/float(w))
```

should be:

```
return value + (v * (self.capacity - weight)/float(w))
```

If `w_i << W` you are overestimating the upper bound by heaps, which causes your branch and bound to never "bound".

### Your second relaxation is not an upper bound

I'm assuming your linear relaxation is for the upper bound. As such your first function to calculate the upper bound is good (bar the bug above). The second function is no longer an upper bound because you are essentially taking a greedy solution as the upper bound.

Example that triggers faulty upper bound:

Define the value and weight of item i as: `v_i` and `w_i` respectively.
Define the ratio of value to weight for item i as: `r_i = v_i / w_i`.
The knapsack can carry at most `W` units of mass.

We have three items as follows:

```
r_0 = k
r_1 = r_2 = k - dk
w_0 = W - dw
w_1 = w_2 = W/2
```

where `k` is an arbitrary constant, `dk` is a small value and `dw` is a value strictly smaller than `W/2` i.e: `dw < W/2`.

Your upper bound algorithm would pick i=0 first and then be unable to add any other items to the knapsack and the achieved value is:

```
   V_ub = r_0*w_0 = k*(W-dw) = k*W - dw*K
```

However the highest attainable value is achieved by taking r_1 and r_2 but not r_0:

```
   V_optimal = r_1*w_1 + r_2*w_2 = 2*r_1*w_1 = 2*(k-dk)*W/2 = k*W - dk*W
```

It is clear that when `dw*K > dk*W` then `V_ub < V_optimal` and your algorithm will cause your branch and bound algorithm to prune sections of the graph that could contain the optimum.

If you are uncertain of the above inequality you can let `dw` approach `W/2` from `0` and let `dk` approach `0` from `k` and see that the limit is trivially:

```
    W/2*K > 0
```

which proves that this scenario is possible and likely to happen when you get enough items.

In comparison, the first upper bound would achieve:

```
V_ub = r_0*w_0 + r_1*(W-w0) = k*(W-dw) + (k-dk)*(W-(W-dw)) = k*W - dw*K + dw*k - dk*dw
     = k*W -dk*dw
```

As `dw < W/2` then `V_ub > V_opt` and it is proved that this is an upper bound.

### Edit/Addendum: Improve your lower bound

You initialize a `best` node with a greedy solution at the start here:
Then you update the `best` solution here (similarly for left node):

```
                if right.V > best.V:            # update our best, if possible 
                    best = right
```

Then you calculate the upper bound with the linear relaxation method:

```
                bound = self._linear_relaxation(index, right.V, right.W)
```

And then only if a branch has a upper bound that is better than the best solution's *partial* value do you continue evaluating the branch:

```
                if bound >= best.V:
                    stack.append(right)
```

This efficiently make the `best` solution's *partial* value your lower bound. The lower and upper bounds should as tightly as possible bound the best achievable value in that branch. Taking the partial value in the branch this far, grossly underestimates the lower bound. Making your search space larger. Remember, your search space grows with your bounds.

You set the lower bound here (similarly for the left case):

```
                right = TreeNode( index + 1, current.V + self.values[index],
                              current.W + self.weights[index], taken )
```

Right.V is used as a lower bound which it technically is, albeit a poor one.

Instead of:

```
                if right.V > best.V:            # update our best, if possible 
                    best = right
```

You should do:

```
    # Somewhere earlier,
    best = self._greedy_solution()
    best_lb = best.V; # Here V is a lower bound on the whole search space. Good!

                # Later on...
                right = TreeNode( index + 1, current.V + self.values[index],
                              current.W + self.weights[index], taken )
                lowerBound = greedy_solution_on_remaining_items(right)
                if lowerBound > best_lb:            # update our best, if possible 
                    best = right
                     best_lb = lowerBound
```

And similar checks for the left case.

Comment: This is great, great work. Do you have any suggestions for further reducing the search space? Can we get a tighter bound, or somehow apply [forward checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-ahead_(backtracking))? This is really what I was after.

Comment: I'm not very good with python, in fact I've never written anything in it. So it would help me greatly if you commented your code a bit. But right now I cannot see anywhere where you are discarding branches that have an upper bound that is lower than the highest lower bound. Meaning that your branch and bound could be incorrectly implemented and you're erroneously searching large parts of the search space.

Comment: Why do you say that? We selectively branch when we decide whether or not to put  an item on the stack:                     `if bound >= best.V: stack.append(right)`

Comment: Comments added!

Comment: My fault, as I said I'm not used to python. So `bound` is your upper bound and `best.V` is the best lower bound? And you're calculating the lower bound here: `current.V + self.values[index]`? If this is the lower bound, it is very loose. In fact you should strive to make it much tighter to prune more candidates earlier. I would try re-using your greedy solver on the partial solutions to get a tighter lower bound.

Comment: The lower bound is the current best solution: If our estimate of what we can get (computed from `_linear_relaxation`) is not better than our best so far, what good is it to continue? I don't think we can improve this. 

Our upper bound would be the fractional solution to the knapsack problem (i.e. when we take a fraction of the highest item ranked by value per unit weight: `return value + (v * (self.capacity weight)/float(w))`. The true solution will always be lower than this, since we can't take a fraction of an item. Does this make sense?

Comment: No, your lower bound (in the code right now) is the value of the best *partial* solution this far. You need to *estimate* a lower bound that is as high as possible for the *entire branch*. See here: `if right.V > best.V: best = right` the higher `right.V` is here, the earlier you can update your lower bound and prune branches. Thus you need to change the way you calculate right.V (and left.V) to take the greedy solution based on the partial solution in that branch.

Comment: Are you saying that rather than testing if `bound >= best.V`, we should test if `bound >= best.V + solution to filling remaining weight with according to greedy algorithm`? 

Should we also create a node corresponding to the greedy solution?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would add this as a comment, but as I am new in here, I can't.
Mathematically speaking, this piece of code `if w > self.capacity - (w + weight):` may not make sense, since you already know that `w + weight <= self.capacity` is false. If my math is not failing me, the "if" statement is always true, since `self.capacity - (w + weight)` is smaller than zero, since `w + weight > self.capacity`, and w > 0.

Am I right?

And yet it doesn't give me the optimal solution.

Comment: It's possible for the code to execute. Please review my logic here starting with, "One optimization (or reduction on a node's upper bound) is to avoid taking items of high value density whose weight exceeds the leftover weight we're trying to fill."

Comment: I'm really sorry but it's not because you can't comment that you should post an answer that is just a comment. You have some options: transform your answer in a real complete answer, or wait to have enough reputation to post your comment. The first one, would be a good option since you're not that far from a good answer, and this would surely earn you reputation!

Comment: @gjdanis, It does execute. My point is: can I remove it? If yes, less computations.

Comment: @Marc-Andre, suggestion accepted. But his question asks how to improve the algorithm. If we can take this piece of code off, it will improve the performance. If it is just a mistake, then it will help him improve the code. Anyway, an improvement.

Comment: +1 Renato is correct. The if-branch will always be taken and the method simplifies to a greedy algorithm. As I said in the second section of my answer. :) Essentially that piece of code simplifies to: `if (w <= capacity - weigh){...}else{if(2*w > capacity - weight){continue;}else{return}` as we entered the else then it is certain that `w > capacity - weight` and thus it follows that `2*w > capacity-weight` always.

Comment: @EmilyL. This isn't necessarily always the case, though. As you correctly prove, it can lead to incorrect pruning.

Comment: @gjdanis, I think you're wrong. In what case would `if w > self.capacity - (w + weight):` evaluate to false if the previous `if w + weight <= self.capacity:` is not taken?

Comment: @EmilyL.: Yes, there's a bug. The code `self.capacity - (w + weight)` assumes you've added `w` to the bag. What we're trying to say is skip the current item if it is heavier than the bag's residual weight. This should be: `w > self.capacity - weight`

Comment: Yes and `if w + weight <= self.capacity` is false, then `w + weight > self.capacity` must be true. Thus the `if` statement will always be taken.

Answer (score 4):

## Readability leads to efficiency

My first recommendation is readability. More readable code makes it easier (for you or others) to understand the algorithm and thus easier to think of efficiency improvements. You are free to choose whatever line length suits you, but if you want other people to be able to read your code easily [79 characters is a good guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

> **Note:** code blocks on Stack Exchange will require horizontal scroll bars beyond 91 characters.
> Some people (including me...) may be less likely to review code that requires scrolling left and right, when there is other code available to review without the inconvenience.

Blank lines can help readability by separating one block of code lines from another. However, using blank lines excessively means they lose their separating purpose and just stretch your code, actually reducing readability. How much is too much and how much is too little is a personal decision, but [this guidance](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) may help.

It's easier to understand a function if it fits on one page. If you have to scroll up and down to view a function then ask yourself if it could be broken down into smaller functions. In this particular case your `solve` method **would** fit on one page if it had fewer blank lines. You could remove some of the blank lines, or split the function into smaller ones. I recommend you do both.

---

## Algorithm fine tuning?

Consider this method:

```
    def _greedy_solution(self):

        weight = 0
        value  = 0
        taken  = []

        for (v, w), index in self.ordered:

            if w + weight <= self.capacity:
                value  += v
                weight += w
                taken.append(index)
```

> ```
>            else:
>                return TreeNode(index, value, weight, taken)
> ```

```
        return TreeNode(index, value, weight, taken)
```

The highlighted `else` block here causes the method to return at the first occurrence of an item that would exceed capacity. Is this what you require? I'm not familiar with the algorithm but I expected that the greedy algorithm would continue considering the less dense items to add any which do not exceed capacity. This means the remaining space will always be used for the most dense of the remaining items that fit. Since the items are sorted according to density (that is, value/weight) the first item that exceeds capacity is not necessarily the last item worth considering. There could still be an item with lower density but smaller weight which would fit.

If I've understood correctly, removing the highlighted `else` block will give you a potentially higher value for your greedy solution, so you can start your `solve` method with a slightly higher lower bound (`best`). This should allow you to discard more of the potential branches later on, saving you unnecessary calculation.

---

## A look at the `solve` method

Here is your `solve` method with some of the blank lines and spaces removed so we can see it all at once for discussion:

```
    def solve(self):
        best = self._greedy_solution()
        root = TreeNode(0, 0, 0, [])
        stack = [root]

        while len(stack) > 0:
            current = stack.pop()
            index   = current.level
            if current.V >= best.V:
                best = current

            if index < len(self.values):
                if current.W + self.weights[index] <= self.capacity:
                    taken = list(current.taken)
                    taken.append(index)
                    right = TreeNode(index + 1, current.V + self.values[index],
                                  current.W + self.weights[index], taken)

                    if right.V > best.V:
                        best = right

                    bound = self._linear_relaxation(index, right.V, right.W)
                    if bound >= best.V:
                        stack.append(right)

                left  = TreeNode(index + 1, current.V, current.W, list(current.taken))
                bound = self._linear_relaxation(index, left.V, left.W)
                if bound >= best.V:
                    stack.append(left)
        return best
```

Consider this section:

```
                    if right.V > best.V:
                        best = right

                    bound = self._linear_relaxation(index, right.V, right.W)
                    if bound >= best.V:
                        stack.append(right)
```

If you have already assigned `best = right` then am I right in thinking that `bound >= best.V` will always be `True`? If so you can avoid the call to `_linear_relaxation` each time right is the new best, like this:

```
                    if right.V > best.V:
                        best = right
                        stack.append(right)
                    else:
                        bound = self._linear_relaxation(index, right.V, right.W)
                        if bound >= best.V:
                            stack.append(right)
```

Before adding `left` or `right` to your tree, you check if `bound >= best.V`. Since `bound` is an upper bound on the possible value obtainable through this branch, it is guaranteed that the branch will not find a better solution that the current `best` if `bound = best.V`. For those occasions when equality occurs, abandoning the branch will save you unnecessary work. So I would recommend replacing `bound >= best.V` with `bound > best.V`, before appending `right` and before appending `left`. There is no point in keeping a branch which can at best provide an equal value solution, since your program is not designed to return multiple solutions.

Comment: Glad to help @gjdanis

Comment: "Since the items are sorted according to density (that is, value/weight) the first item that exceeds capacity is not necessarily the last item worth considering." Very, very good way to say it!